# Access the index of a pandas series

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, series

I am trying to identify which word is the most counted in a pandas dataframe (df_temp in my code). Also I have this :

```
 l = df_temp['word'].count_values()
```

l is then obviously a pandas series where the first row points toward the most counted index (in my case the most counted word) in df_temp['word']. Although I can see the word in my console, I cannot get it properly. The only way I found so far is to transform it into a dictionary so I have :

```
dl = dict(l)
```

and then I can easily retrieve my index...after sorting the dictionary. Obviously this does the job, but I am pretty sure you have a smarter solution as this one is very dirty and inelegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Pandas you can find the most frequent value in the `word` column:

```
df['word'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

and this code below will give you the count for that value, which is the max count in that column:

```
df['word'].value_counts().max()
```

Answer (score 3):

The `index` of the result of `value_counts()` are your values:

```
l.index
```

will give you the values that were counted

Example:

```
In [163]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['hello','world','python','hello','python','python']})
df

Out[163]:
        a
0   hello
1   world
2  python
3   hello
4  python
5  python

In [165]:    
df['a'].value_counts()

Out[165]:
python    3
hello     2
world     1
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [164]:    
df['a'].value_counts().index

Out[164]:
Index(['python', 'hello', 'world'], dtype='object')
```

So basically you can get a specific word count by indexing the series:

```
In [167]:
l = df['a'].value_counts()
l['hello']

Out[167]:
2
```

Comment: If you wanted a negative index search as in "values with all words that are NOT python". Is that `l[-['python']]` or `l[l != ['python']]`?

Comment: @PierreLafortune you'd have to do `df[~df['a'].str.contains('python')]`

Comment: But that doesn't give the value counts. Would you then extend that to `df[~df['a'].str.contains('python')]['a'].value_counts()`?

Comment: @PierreLafortune sorry I didn't understand your question, do `l[~l.index.str.contains('python')]`